# Identify row matches across multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have been given a table that is populated by '1' and '0' based on the yes/no answers to a survey. I have been asked to identify all totally distinct answers, i.e. People who answered 'Yes' to questions 1, 17, 23, 234 and 238.
There are many columns (500+) and thus many answer permutations.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which RDBMS and can you provide some sample input and output?

Comment: SQL Server 2000.
Unfortunately, I do not have any example data (542 questions would be a lot to upload). The survey is being completed as we speak, and so I have been given an idea on what the table would look like.
Tought I would do my homework first....

Answer (score 1):

Employ your text editor or use your database tool to produce a list of the column names,

then just do this

```
select max(person_id)
from answer_table 
group by (
  a1,a2,a3,....  -- paste list of columns here.
  )
having count(
  a1,a2,a3....
  ) = 1; -- return only answer sets that have no duplicate
```

`max(person_id)` will pull out the single person's ID without breaking the GROUP BY.

Comment: Ah, my interpretation of distinct answers included distinct people as well, but that's probably not correct.

Comment: There are only certain questions that relate to the person completing the form. I believe (and hope) these will be given a unique ID. I can omit those column names from the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: oh, yeah whoops... there would be a person ID in there wouldn't there.... OK, code edited.

Answer (score 0):

The specific numbers you mention are a bit confusing: are they just an example?

You are aware of the `DISTINCT` statement in sql? That, and correct selection of which columns you want, should solve your problem.

Byron's answer (now deleted: it had a select distinct with all 500 columns written out long hand) is good, and makes use of explicit column names, which is good practise in many cases. If you want shorter notation, your sql version may support `Select Distinct *`.

Comment: The numbers mentioned were just an example.
I must admit that I wasn't aware that the DISTINCT clause could be used across multiple columns (novice enthusiast - sorry).

Answer (score 0):

```
select count(distinct col_name) from table_name where answer = '1' and id in (1,17,23,234,238)
```

Comment: i think each column represent question and each row represent user entry

Comment: Correct, and the numbers given were just an example, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The following statements assumes your input is 2,3 and column names are 2Q,3Q ...

```
DECLARE @QueryInput VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Query nVARCHAR(4000)
SET     @QueryInput = '2,3'
SET     @QueryInput = REPLACE(@QueryInput,',','=1 AND Q')
SET     @QueryInput = 'Q'+@QueryInput
SET     @QueryInput = @QueryInput+'=1'

PRINT   @QueryInput

SET     @Query = 'SELECT * FROM answer_table WHERE  '+@QueryInput
PRINT   @Query
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Query
```